# R Extract patterns in strings vectorised within a dataframe

Tags: r, string, replace

I have a dataframe with a 'description' column that I require to split into 'product' and 'facetblock' columns. I have mocked up some dummy data to illustrate my task. I have (through a process of using RWeka::NGramTokenizer) been successful in generating the 'product' column.

The data looks like ...

```
my_dataframe = data.frame(description = c("ford fiesta blue fast","red toyota japanese very fast","rolls royce phantom black",
                                      "yellow beach buggie with spare wheel","harrier jump jet vertical take off",
                                      "american jeep with seat belt","suzuki motorbike with built in fridge"),
                      product = c("fiesta","red toyota","rolls royce","beach buggie","jump jet","american jeep","motorbike"))
```

I am stuck though on my next step and would be very appreciative of any help please. I am trying to extract the strings in 'product' from its relative position in 'description'. For the avoidance of doubt my target my_dataframe$facetblock column would look like this...

```
my_dataframe$facetblock = c("ford blue fast", "japanese very fast", "phantom black", "yellow with spare wheel", "harrier vertical take off", "with seat belt", "suzuki with built in fridge")
```

I have tried a number of different out of the box approaches from the base, stringr, stringi and qdap packages (grep, str_extract, stri_extract, mgsub) but without success. I have tried writing my own sapply functions also but no luck yet

```
my_dataframe$facetblock = sapply(mydata, function(x) str_extract(mydata$description[x], mydata$product[x]))

my_dataframe$facetblock = sapply(mydata$description, function(x) grep(mydata$product[x], mydata$description[x], value = TRUE, invert = TRUE))
```

Does anyone have a solution they could share with me please? Thnx in advance.

Comment: Try `library(stringi) ; with(my_dataframe, stri_replace_first_fixed(description, product, "")`

Comment: Or `sapply(1:7,function(x){sub(paste0(data$product[x],' '),'',data$description[x])})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could vectorize this using `stri::stri_replace_first_fixed` (you can change to `last`/`all` too)

```
library(stringi) 
with(my_dataframe, stri_replace_first_fixed(description, product, ""))
# [1] "ford  blue fast"              " japanese very fast"          " phantom black"               "yellow  with spare wheel"    
# [5] "harrier  vertical take off"   " with seat belt"              "suzuki  with built in fridge"
```

If you don't like the leading spaces you can wrap it up into the new `trimws` or `stringi::stri_trim` (as per @akruns comment) functions.

Comment: If you are using `stringi`, then `stri_trim` would be an option (+1)

Comment: Thanks @David and etienne. David's answer did the trick. Much obliged!